# Appendix changes sections and figures numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, koma-script, punctuation, appendices

I don't know how to face a strange behavior caused by the appendix package.
I'm using KOMA-Script book class and many other packages (see here: http://pastie.org/1728702)

When I add an appendix (not the package, the `\appendix` command or the appendix block) at the end of the document, figures and sections get a final dot. For example

> Fig 5.4.:
>
> 5.1. Section title
>
> 5.1.1. Subsection title

Has anyone already experienced this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `appendix` package is not the culprit. Adding a final dot to sectioning and figure/table numbers in case an appendix is present is the documented default behaviour of `KOMA-Script`. To remove the dot, add the class option `numbers=noendperiod`.