# Changed style of caption numbering

Tags: numbering, captions, punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appendix changes sections and figures numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15444/appendix-changes-sections-and-figures-numbering)

I have a problem with some captions in a document I am currently working on. Usually when I compile the main file, all the information of Figure and Table will be written as:

```
Figure 4.1: Architecture
```

However, since couple of days (I am not aware exactly since when), when I compile it, it changes the numbering into:

```
Figure 4.1.: Architecture
```

As you see there is an additional (point) after 4.1(.) in the second one.

I am not sure, but this happens to all my Figures, Tables, Chapters also. (So its not `4.2 Subsection Two`, but it becames `4.2. Subsection Two`). During the changes I remember I never installed any additional package or anything.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Wild guess: You are using a `KOMA-Script` class and have recently added an appendix chapter/section? If so, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15444/appendix-changes-sections-and-figures-numbering

Comment: BTW, looking at your user profil page, it seems you have not cast any votes so far. Please consider to upvote helpful questions and answers, especially answers to your own questions. (Note that upvoting has to be done separately from accepting an answer.)

Comment: @locstep : Yes, you are correct, and many thank you for your tips :)